# "Ethernet" doesn't have a valid IP configuration - win 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet

(note I read all the related posts here)

Every few hours the wired internet stops for a few hours. the other computers and the wireless at home do have internet. when I connect the problematic pc I do have internet.

this is what I have tried.
1. Did almost everything I have found here.
2. tried this: https://windows10skill.com/ethernet-doesnt-have-a-valid-ip-configuration-windows-10/#1
3. replaced the cable
4. reset the router
5. changed to another port in the router
6. windows diagnostics, here is the result: https://justpaste.it/1kctb

[image]

[image]

Comment: And where is your "invalid configuration"? What kind if invalidity? Try: disable connection, find its sub-section by IP in registry (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces), remove its sub-section, reboot, set correct parameters for connection, enable connection, check.

Comment: Try to install the Realtek PCIe GBE / 2.5G Family Controller driver for Windows 10 at [this link](https://realtek-download.com/realtek-pcie-gbe-family-controller/).

Answer (score 1):

I was also running into this exact same issue. I tried all the options available out there. Changing the cable, re-installing the driver, resetting the ipconfig, manually setting the DNS address etc etc. Nothing worked.

I played around with the modem's settings and to my surprise it worked.

I changed following settings:

> WAN Operation Mode: “Router Mode IPv4 + IPv6

to

> WAN Operation Mode: “Router Mode IPv4-Only"

Restarted the router. The ethernet was up and running. Didn't affect the wireless connection on the laptop.

Comment: Rather than posting the exact same answer to multiple questions you should be specifically tailoring your answer to suit OP. If a question is exactly identical and can be answered by exactly the same answer then you should be flagging to close one of the questions as a duplicate instead of posting duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens either when your IP config for the adapter is no longer correct for the network or when someone didn't know what they were doing. Assuming you have admin privileges, try this:

1. Right click on your network icon in your taskbar and click on **Open Network & Internet Settings**
2. Click **Change adapter options**
3. Right click your **Ethernet** adapter and click **Properties**
4. In the list, click on **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)** and click **Properties**
5. Set the options to obtain automatically and then clikc **OK**
6. Click **OK** on the Ethernet Properties Window. Give it a few seconds and it should work properly.

If that doesn't work, try disabling and re-enabling the adapter or uninstall it in Device Manager and reboot the PC. It'll automatically reinstall.